# Can't display JSON results on in a HOME.VC text label

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to display a Json result (temperature and Humidity) on my view controller (respectively temperatureDisp and humidityDisp), but it does not seem to work.

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var usernameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var temperatureDisp: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var humidityDisp: UILabel!

    @IBAction func logoutTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain!)

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
        if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as! NSString as String
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url2 : String = "http://admin:xxxxxxx@xxxxxx/xxxxx.fr/metrics2.php"
        var request2 : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request2.URL = NSURL(string: url2)
        request2.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request2, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            var  error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
            let jsonResult : NSArray! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as! NSArray
            if (jsonResult != nil) {
                println(jsonResult)

            } else {
                println("There is a problem")
            }

            var temperature = jsonResult[0].valueForKey("temperature") as! String
            var humidity = jsonResult[0].valueForKey("humidite") as! String

            println(temperature)
            println(humidity)


            self.humidityDisp.text = temperature

        })


    }


}}
```

That is how the variable jsonResult looks :

```
(
        {
        Id = 117;
        date = "2015-04-06";
        humidite = "45.3";
        login = raspberrypi;
        luminosite = "\U00e9teinte";
        temperature = "18.4";
        time = "16:25:21";
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it does not seem to work", but from your code I can assume at least that you are not getting the values you expect from your JSON result, but more likely your app is crashing like crazy.  If you want to write applications in Swift you absolutely must understand optionals and learn how to properly work with them.  Read [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/)—and thoroughly.  As your code is now, by force unwrapping using `as!` and using implicitly unwrapped types (those followed by `!`) you are ignoring the entire concept of optionals and opening yourself up to crashes.

So, assuming that there is no network or parsing errors, and assuming that the JSON string you're parsing has an array as its root object, the following should work.  I've taken the liberty of typing and unwrapping your variables appropriately, as well as cleaning up some of the cruft.

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var temperatureDisp: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var humidityDisp: UILabel!

    @IBAction func logoutTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain)
        }
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let isLoggedIn = prefs.boolForKey("ISLOGGEDIN")
        if isLoggedIn {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
        } else {
            if let username = prefs.stringForKey("USERNAME") {
                self.usernameLabel.text = username
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url2 = "http://admin:xxxxxxx@xxxxxx/xxxxx.fr/metrics2.php"
        var request2 = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request2.URL = NSURL(string: url2)
        request2.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request2, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) in
            var parseError:NSError?

            if let data = data, let jsonResults = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError) as? NSArray {

                println( jsonResults )

                if let result = jsonResults.firstObject as? [String : AnyObject] {
                    if let humidity = result["humidite"] as? String {
                        self.humidityDisp.text = humidity
                    }
                    if let temperature = result["temperature"] as? String {
                        self.temperatureDisp.text = temperature
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println("There is a problem: \(parseError)" )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! Now, it does work perfectly. I will definitely read the recommended literature and try to improve.